# Selenium fluent wait not finding element

Tags: java, selenium

I have a page that executes multiple ajax requests. When all requests have returned a class called `loading-complete` is added to the body element. In selenium I try to wait for this class to exist before I start looking for elements to verify. This is the method:

```
public static final long DEFAULT_POLL_INTERVAL = 1L;
public static final long DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 60L;

public static void waitForLoadingComplete(WebDriver driver) {
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = IkWaitUtil.createFluentWait(driver, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, DEFAULT_POLL_INTERVAL);
    wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver arg0) {
            return arg0.findElement(By.cssSelector("body.loading-complete"));
        }
    });
}
```

This fails at seemingly random with the following error and stack trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for mypackage.util.MyUtil$10@17667bd
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'my_host', ip: 'a.b.c.d', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
    at mypackage.util.MyUtil.waitForLoadingComplete(MyUtil.java:287)
    at mypackage.util.MyUtil.getDisplayedWebElement(MyUtil.java:217)
    at mypackage.util.MyUtil.getDisplayedWebElement(MyUtil.java:212)
    at mypackage.bdd.MyCommonSteps.openAndSearch(MyCommonSteps.java:116)
    at mypackage.bdd.MyCommonSteps.givenSearchRequisites(MyCommonSteps.java:31)
    at mypackage.bdd.subpackage.StatusSteps.givenTheUserSearches(StatusSteps.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParameterizedStep.perform(StepCreator.java:428)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner$FineSoFar.run(StoryRunner.java:436)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runStepsWhileKeepingState(StoryRunner.java:419)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runScenarioSteps(StoryRunner.java:384)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runParametrisedScenariosByExamples(StoryRunner.java:363)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runIt(StoryRunner.java:256)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.run(StoryRunner.java:181)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.run(StoryRunner.java:164)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$EnqueuedStory.call(Embedder.java:620)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$EnqueuedStory.call(Embedder.java:584)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == body.loading-complete (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.20 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'my_host', ip: 'a.b.c.d', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Session ID: 0f5db388-ce4b-4310-ad4a-edc452bf5f40
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=11, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:17512/, handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:441)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:426)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at mypackage.util.MyUtil$10.apply(MyUtil.java:290)
    at mypackage.util.MyUtil$10.apply(MyUtil.java:287)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    ... 25 more
```

So, since my method is working sometimes and sometimes not, and the failures seem random to me (testing manually shows the class is set), I wonder if I am implementing this incorrectly. Is it better with shorter timeout and multiple retries or is there someway to make the behaviour stable and repeatable?

Comment: The best guess is: Sometimes loading takes more than 60s. Use a longer timeout. Try 600s. Timeout does not mean pause.

Comment: And, why do not you use just Explicit wait?

Comment: @Würgspaß That is true, I should have mentioned that all testing is performed against mocks and loading never takes more then a second when using the site manually.

Comment: @Saifur It has been my understanding that FluentWaits are a good way to do this. I would be very glad to learn more about Explicit wait and how it could help in solving issues like this.

Comment: @span Are you sure? There is a timeout exception in your Stacktrace at `FluentWait.until`. The reason (according to Javadoc) is: _TimeoutException - If the timeout expires._

Comment: @Würgspaß well, I can't be sure what happens when they are executed by the driver. I know that no team member have experienced something that would trigger a timeout. We suspect the driver to be buggy or getting stuck but have no clue on how to investigate or work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a loading indicator. That's even better for Explicit wait. Just give a little bit about the Explicit wait, it sleeps for 500ms by default and sends a request to see if the element is there or not until the timeout reached. I see that as the best fit in this case.

```
By css = By.cssSelector("body.loading-complete"));
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(css))
```

This wait should simply wait upto 10s and check the presence of element every 500ms

Answer (score 0):

For your immediate problem I would strongly suggest to increase the timeout. According to the stacktrace this is the problem:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds
>   waiting

As for explicit wait, this should help:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 600000L, 2000L).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("body.loading-complete")));
```

Waiting up to 10 minutes, polling every 2 seconds.