# screenshot of web page not being captured intermittently

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, snapshot

I am executing a test case using selenium web driver and capturing snapshot of the web page using following code.

```
// following code executes the logout button on the portal.

Config.firefox_dri.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='dropdown-parent']/div[@class='account']/div[@class='fleft']")).click();
Config.firefox_dri.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='settings-item']/a[@id='logout']")).click();

//below code takes the snapshot of the web page after logging out.

try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    File scrFile =     ((TakesScreenshot)Config.firefox_dri).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(screen_shot_file_name));

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but problem which i am facing with the snapshot is sometimes the snappshot is captured while on some occasion a blank snapshot or a snapshot of a partial web page is captured. 
I have also tried it after inserting some wait so that the page gets loaded before the snapshot is captured. but the issue still persists. the code is written in Java and the functionality to logout of the portal is working correctly. Please help.

Comment: Have you try to use wait.untill()?

Comment: instead of thread.sleep(3000), wait.untill('locate an element which make sure page has loaded' )

Comment: The answers to this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914331/selenium-fluent-wait-not-finding-element/30916590#30916590